# The difference between 例え and 例えば

Tags: word-choice, words, usage

For a long time I have roughly approximated 例えば to 'for example' and thought of 例え as a word to emphasize ～ても and similar constructions, but in the lyrics to [Ash like Snow](http://www.kasi-time.com/item-28631.html) by The Brilliant Green, 例えば seems to be used like 例え.

> 例えば光が消え失せて　この地球{ほし}が堕ちても

Is 例えば really being used like 例え, or am I misinterpreting it? Is this poetic licence? Does this 例えば belong to one of the meanings [here](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/137788/meaning/m0u/)?

Comment: It's just an ordinary 例えば, meaning "let us say", "suppose" etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case, 「例{たと}えば」 is used to mean 「もしも」.  That is to say that it is used to assume a situation -- "***if, for instance,***".

Obviously, that is not the most common meaning/usage of 「例えば」, but every good dictionary will give that definition.

It so happens that the lyrics would still make sense if 「例えば」 were to be replaced by 「例え」, but I would think that the writer actually meant to use 「例えば」 there.  IMHO, therefore, it is not a matter of poetic licence.

> "Does this 例えば belong to one of the meanings here?"

Yes, it is definition #3 there.

Answer (score 1):

> 例えば光が消え失せて　この地球｛ほし｝が堕ちても

I visited the site and read the whole lyrics of **Ash like Snow**, and I found that the 「例えば」 should be written 「例え」in this phrase as a natural Japanese.

> For a long time I have roughly approximated 例えば to 'for example' and thought of 例え as a word to emphasize ～ても and similar constructions

I certify that you correctly understand the meanings of 例えば and 例え, and the difference between them.

Comment: This answer isn't really satisfactory. Is there a reason, other than syllable count, that the songwriter would have chosen 例えば instead of 例え?

Comment: 例えば is used to show an example of a fact, but 地球が堕｛お｝ちる is not a fact, so you usually can't show/tell/say the pharase with 例えば. 例え … ても is usually show/tell/say something that never happens.

Comment: 例えば is used not only to tell a fact, but a possible thing to happen.